# Equality condition on Holder's inequality for matrix for infinity norm

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

The equality condition for Holder's inequality, $\text{Tr}A^*B \leq ||A||_p||B||_q $ is $|A|^p = \lambda |B|^q$ for scaler $\lambda > 0$. What happens when $p$ or $q$ is $\infty$? I found out that Remark 2.2 in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05377.pdf) seems to argue that the equality condition holds when $|B|$ has an eigenvalue of $|B|_\infty$. Am I interpreting correctly?

If so, I have related question. Suppose $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0& 1 & 0&0 \\ 0& 0& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B$ is also $4$ by $4$ Hermitian rank 2 matrix with eigenvalues $\pm b$ (or equilvanelty one can think of difference between two pure density matrices as $B$). Then, the holder's inequality gives:

$
Tr(AB) \leq |A|_1|B|_\infty = 2b.
$

Since $B$ has eigenvalues of $\pm b$, $B^2$ has an eigenvalue of $b$. Then $|B|=\sqrt{B^2}$ also has $b = |B|_\infty$ as an eigenvalue. So it seems like the equality condition for Holder's inequality holds so that the maximum value of $Tr(AB) = 2b$. However, I'm having trouble of finding what $B$ matrix indeed gives $Tr(AB) = 2b$. All I could see is placing $+b$ on one of the first two diagonals of $B$ and placing $-b$ on one of the last two diagonals of $B$, for example: $B = \begin{pmatrix} b & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0& 0 & 0&0 \\ 0& 0& -b& 0 \\ 0& 0& 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which gives $Tr(AB) = b$. What am I missing here?

Comment: What about $D=\text{diag}(b,b,-b,-b)$?

Comment: @DaftWullie I forgot to mention, $B$ is a rank-2 matrix!